# Is it possible to find a google id from an oAuth 2.0 token stored in my database

Tags: database, oauth-2.0

I have a database where Google drive OAuth 2.0 tokens are stored.

There are several thousands of records and I just realized that I forgot to save the google id in the database.

Is it possible to find a google id from this kind of database record:

```
{"access_token":"XXXXXXXXXXX","token_type":"Bearer","expires_in":3600,"id_token":"YYYYYYYY","created":1379455302}
```

this is my config.:

```
Access Type: online
Approuval: Auto
Scopes: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get the metadata for whatever record you need based on a query of your stored data

Comment: I'm not familiar with the api but usually they usually provide query langauges for their data.